# Is "as" a synonym for "similar to"

Tags: word-usage

Can I replace `similar to` with `as`?

Instead of saying

> Anyway, similar to the abstract, this is the last thing to be written.

I would say

> Anyway, as the abstract, this is the last thing to be written.

Thanks

Comment: Who deletes my comments? I said that **as** doesn't really mean **similar to** but **like** might. As Peter wrote in his answer **just like** is even better. Another possible choice is **so as**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence

> Anyway, ***similar to*** the abstract, this is the last thing to be written.

might be rewritten as

> Anyway, ***just as*** the abstract, this is the last thing to be written.
>   *anyway, just like the abstract, this is the last thing to be written*

if you insist on using "*as*", although "*just like*" may be a more natural choice.